# Adding Two Subtotals in SSRS to Another Cell

Tags: ssrs-2008, subtotal, ssrs-expression

I've got a report that I want to sum some of the columns and then do some basic subtraction on the summations on a row underneath.  In my screenshot, I've got the columns summing correctly, and the row is hidden which is what I'm looking for.

But I'm not sure how or if I can then take the Sum(Prod_Coll) minus Sum(Proc_Perf) and make that value display in the bottom right cell (Drop Total Here).

[image: Subtracting Subtotals]

Is this possible to do within SSRS?

Comment: Yes you can do that as long as it is on the same dataset and same tablix. If it is different dataset then you might want to use the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the empty cell, click create placeholder, click the Fx button next to value and enter:

```
=sum(prod_coll)-Sum(Proc_Perf)
```

That should do it unless I'm missing something.